# missing \item in table despite clear item

Tags: tables, koma-script, itemize, tabulary

I need to have lists in a table environment.
This returns the error "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."

The following MWE replicates the issue. I have just updated all packages in MikTeX (on Windows).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} 

\newenvironment{compactitemt}{\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide=0pt,
%left=0pt %for neat, wide=0pt %for flush left to save space
before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
after ={\end{minipage}} ]   }{ \end{itemize} }

%%%%%                           Tables and graphics
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{table}\centering
        \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{l l} 
            test & 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item table item 1
            \end{itemize}
            \\ 
        \end{tabulary}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have left in packages that are required for different tables, and the environment "compactitemt" that I actually want to use instead of "itemize" in the table. This includes a minipage environment, but both give the same error. I am also sure that this worked previously, in a file I worked in a year ago, but this also gives an error now. What could be the cause?